# The correct way to copy a field's data to another field in the same table with groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm writing my first groovy script to update  the whole database table. Basically I want the number is the ID field to be put into ANOTHER_ID field

```
 import groovy.sql.Sql

def url = project.getProperty("database.url")
def driver = project.getProperty("database.driver")
def user = project.getProperty("database.user")
def pass = project.getProperty("database.pass")
def output = properties['output']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, pass, driver)
def outwriter = new PrintWriter(output)

sql.eachRow("select * from THE_TABLE", { row ->
    def id = row.id
    outwriter.println "Update THE_TABLE set (ANOTHER_ID)=(${id});"
} );

outwriter.close()
sql.close()
```

I'm posting to make sure I'm doing this correctly or if there is a better way of updating my table.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with the SQL you're generating, it should be:

```
outwriter.println "UPDATE THE_TABLE SET ANOTHER_ID = ${row.id} WHERE id = ${row.id} ;"
```

However, you can replace this whole loop and everything with

```
outwriter.println "UPDATE THE_TABLE SET ANOTHER_ID = id ;"
```

Which will set every row in a single query instead of needing an `UPDATE` per row